# Audio breakpoints on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, skrollr

I'm developing a one page website with Skrollr.js plugin. I need to add multiple audio tracks to specific pixel heights and stop these tracks in multiple breakpoints. How can I do that?

I tried with the script below, but I don't know how to add multiple conditions with other breakpoints, tracks, and pixel height.

```
var playing = false;
var audioTrack = $('#track1').get(0);

window.onscroll = function() {
  var winH = $(window).height();
  var scrollPage = $(window).scrollTop();

  if(!playing && winH >= 768 && scrollPage > 1000 && scrollPage < 3000){
    audioTrack.play();
    playing = true;
  }else if(scrollPage > 3000 || scrollPage < 1000 || winH < 768 ){
    audioTrack.pause();
    audioTrack.currentTime = 0;
    playing = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to make things more generic & break the problem down more. Separate out audio playing/pausing functions, a function to get/set the current audio track, and/or a function to check the scroll position that sets the track & play/pause state. Trying to do all of that in 1 function is too limiting and not reusable, as you've discovered.

Comment: Without commenting anything about the actual way that script works, I just want to add that you are using pixel values here (for scroll values), but these will NOT correspond to the different sections on different devices (desktop/tablet/phone etc.), i.e. the whole thing will have serious flaws if your website is supposed to be responsive

Comment: Thanks for your answers. To mc01: can you post an example of what did you say? I'm a noob with javascript XD. To Johannes: my website isn't designed to be responsive, but for only 4-5 widescreen sizes. My problem is to make audio breakpoints for these 4-5 sizes.